# Theano : Can we reuse compile files generated by theano?

Tags: theano, theano-cuda

Uisng compile, Theano generates C++ code along with Cuda code and compiled lib.
Can we reuse those ones after ?

Comment: Are you asking if you have to permission to reuse those files or how to reuse them?

Answer (score 0):

You *could* load them as a python module from the cache or just copy the code somewhere else and modify it to have a friendlier name.

Also there is a project to have Theano produce a some C code for a library that I know works for some situations but has never really been finished.  If you are interested in that I would ask on the theano-dev mailing list.

Comment: It's a python module so just place it in your python path and import it.